# Redis cluster configuration for Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I am going to add a redis cluster for my spring boot application. I find below properties need to be place under application.property file in order to achieve it.

```
spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects= # Maximum number of redirects to follow when executing commands across the cluster.
spring.redis.cluster.nodes= # Comma-separated list of "host:port" pairs to bootstrap from.
```

What is **max-redirects** and what value should I put?

Also how does the redis pool behave with redis cluster? Is there any different for redis cluster compare with single redis node for below redis pool values?

```
spring.redis.pool.max-active
spring.redis.pool.max-idle
spring.redis.pool.max-wait
spring.redis.pool.min-idle
```

Comment: Each property contains a description, check out the documentation for `spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects`.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave `max-redirects` unconfigured so [defaults will apply](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.java#L304).

Redis Cluster support using Jedis considers pooling settings from `spring.redis.pool.…`, there's no separate configuration. These settings allow you to configure pooling once and use pooling with different operation modes (Standalone, Sentinel, Cluster).